# Looking for biographical info on R' Yehuda HaLevi Lifschitz

Tags: historical-figures

There is a *sefer* which I encountered called Derech Emunah written by a R' Yehuda HaLevi Lifschitz.  Everything that I know about him is the information found on [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/6830) title page of his *sefer*, and that he quotes freely from both Nefesh HaChaim and Tanya, referring to both authors with glowing terms of approbation.

I am interested in finding out more about the author, particularly who he studied from and what his sphere of influence was.

Where can I find out more about him?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=wRrc2qJh68cC&pg=PA342&lpg=PA342&dq=Yehuda+HaLevi+Lifschitz&source=bl&ots=W2Bs-IOQ4R&sig=cxsOhKwxnZ6YDOu3Dp1TmITAl7k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=X4WBVbWQAcq5ggSJkID4BA&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=Yehuda%20HaLevi%20Lifschitz&f=false

Comment: http://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/meretch/meretch1a.html

Comment: @GershonGold thanks, that was a good start.

Answer (score 3):

His relative, R' Yaakov Lifschitz, wrote a sefer called Toldos Yitzchak where he writes in [the introduction](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46877&st=&pgnum=3) (at the bottom) that R' Yehuda Lifschitz helped support his efforts. That sefer is about the life of [R' Yitzchak Elchanan Spektor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Elchanan_Spektor)<sup>*</sup>, the namesake of the Rabbi Isaac Elchanan Theological Seminary, a part of Yeshiva University.

R' Yehuda Lifschitz also wrote a Sefer called [דור ישרים](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/43849), published posthumously, as a response to and condemnation of דור דור ודורשיו by [Issac Hirsh Weiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Hirsch_Weiss). It has [approbations from several people](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43850&st=&pgnum=3&hilite=), primarily from the Litvish world, such as R. Chaim Ozer Grodzinski, and figures from Volozhin, Telz and other places. As the introduction in [Derech Emuna](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6830&st=&pgnum=7&hilite=) lays out, it was also written in response to the same work.

He also wrote a sefer called [נחל יהודה](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/34137) which seems to be more conventional Torah ideas rather than refutations of other ideas. It doesn't contain much introduction.

It seems quite likely the first entry [here](http://www.myheritage.com/names/yehuda_lifschitz) is him, but for an additional middle name that is not printed in the seforim. But the timeline and father's name match. That would mean he lived from 1829 to 1905.

So from all of this his general sphere of influence was the traditional Litvish groups of the 19th century.

<sup>*As far as I can tell, that is the intended person, I didn't see the last name mentioned.</sup>

Comment: So where did he study and from whom per the OPs question

Comment: @Mefaresh, the OP asked for biography focused on teacher and sphere of influence. This answer answers the latter.